# List item's custom workflow instance id

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, rest

Is there any way to get list item's workflow instance id? (SharePoint 2016)

I can get for list association with REST Api `https://[server]/[sitecollection]/[site]/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('[ListTitle]')/WorkflowAssociations`

But i need list item's workflow instance id.

When i try with WorkflowInstanceID, always returns null. I've attached two custom workflow to a library. And i need to get their instance id. So;

`/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Your Library Name')/Items?$select=WorkflowInstanceID` always returns null

Thank you